# best way ( short hand) adding column and row to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

What is the best way to concatenate column or row in numpy?

I know of numpy.append and numpy.vstack.

for example, i have 3x5 array and 3x5 array

```
a = numpy.zeros((3,5))
b = numpy.ones((3,5))
```

If I want to concatenate a and b to make 3 x 10 array, i would do

```
a = numpy.hstack((a,b))
```

If I want to concatenate a and b to make 6 x 5 array, i would do

```
a = numpy.vstack((a,b))
```

is there a more efficient(more array-ish) syntax like in R?

Comment: You need to give us a better example, such as a couple of input arrays, and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hstack` and `vstack` both end up calling `concatenate`, which is a compiled function.  So it's as efficient as can be.

```
In [76]: np.concatenate([a,b],1).shape
Out[76]: (3, 10)
In [77]: np.concatenate([a,b],0).shape
Out[77]: (6, 5)
In [79]: np.array([a,b]).shape
Out[79]: (2, 3, 5)
```

And `np.array` is the basic constructor, which normally adds a dimension.  The input to all of these is a list, a list of arrays, lists, or numbers.

What is special about `R` syntax that makes more efficient or 'arrayish'?

Comment: I remember it wrong. R uses rbind and cbind. THank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You can do shorthand like so:

```
import numpy as np

a = numpy.zeros((3,5))
b = numpy.ones((3,5))

# hstack equivalent
c = np.c_[a, b]

# vstack equivalent
d = np.r_[a, b]
```